# Printing an ArrayList of files read in from a directory - JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I am attempting to print all objects of an `ArrayList` but encountering problems.

I originally output a bunch of `.txt` files that I am wanting to read in to another `ArrayList` and then output that.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have 5 .txt files, each consisting of a single line of text. The code I have to try and bring things in looks like so:

```
public void listfiles() {
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Polymer\\QAworkbook");
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()));
    for (File x : files) {
        System.out.println(f.toString());
    }
}
```

At the moment, the code ouputs the file path, but for the amount of times that there are files present.

Comment: Typo. **`System.out.println(x.toString());`** - for each `x` in `files` print `f` is what you wrote.